# So what exactly am I supposed to do as a Medium in Town of Salem?

Tags: town-of-salem

As a medium, you are able to talk to the dead in the night and you can whisper to the living when you are dead. But what exactly are you supposed to ask them? Nobody knows by whom they got killed. What is the purpose of this role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to do...

1. You can find out from an Investigator, Sheriff, or Lookout the results of their investigations the night they die.  Put them in your own will if you don't think it's safe to reveal you're a Medium.
2. Spy stills sees Mafia chat when dead.  They can tell you what they see and who is visited.
3. People cleaned by a Janitor can tell you what their roles are and what their wills say.
4. The dead can sometimes figure out things out that the living have missed.
5. Dead Mafia members may be able to tell you who the Neutral Killing roles are... Mafia rarely have "real" wills.
6. You can sometimes find out if there is a second Medium.  You cannot see the other Medium's text, but the dead players can.
7. Dead players can reveal that their identity was stolen by a Disguiser.

Comment: If you're ever jailed, you can reveal to the Jailor what you've found out without having to say it during the day in public.

Comment: Once the Forger makes it to the game, people will be able to tell you that their will was a forgery and what their real will said.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Medium is to find out information that the dead players know, especially given that you are 100% certain of their role once they are dead.  So a dead Sheriff can be relied upon to give accurate information about who they suspected or cleared.

In a well played game, where all the roles keep accurate last will entries, a Medium may not be able to glean much information, though the dead table talk may provide some extra information as the dead compare notes. However, they are still extremely important as a Town vote for lynching known enemies.  I've had many games lost where we as the Town knew who was evil, but could not muster enough votes to deal with them.